# How get assembly name from array of byte that contains assembly?

Tags: .net

I receive byte array what contains assembly data.
How i can get assembly name from this data without loading assembly in appdomain ?

```
var assemblyName = GetAssemblyName(byte[] asmData);//doesn't load assembly to appDomain.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the assembly name without loading it into the current app domain, create a new AppDomain, use [AppDomain.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7hcs6az6.aspx) then call the FullName property. For example:

```
byte[] asmData;  // Contains the assembly data

AppDomain appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyDomain");
Assembly assembly = appDomain.Load(asmData);
string name = assembly.FullName;
AppDomain.Unload(appDomain);
```

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173101%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), assuming no other domains have loaded that assembly, it should be unloaded without being loaded into the current app domain.

If you do not want to load it into any app domain, save the bytes to a file and use [AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.getassemblyname.aspx) method.

Comment: Thank you for answer.
I think it to expensive way for getting assembly identity information.

Comment: @void If speed is critical, can the caller supply the assembly name with the byte array?

Comment: Yes, it can. We did so. But detection name of assembly from byte array on fly was preferable.